# How to labeling with Pandas (.map)?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

label with pandas (.map) in the following table

```
m2m_similarity.columns = ['MoviId 1','MoviId 2','similarity_score']
m2m_similarity.head(3)
```

I have tried to get the label slightly-similar, similar, and exacly

```
m2m_similarity['analysis'] = m2m_similarity['similarity_score'].map({
    0.1: 'slightly-similar', 0.2: 'slightly-similar', 0.3: 'slightly-similar', 0.4: 'slightly-similar',
    0.5: 'similar', 0.6: 'similar', 0.7: 'similar', 0.8: 'similar',0.9: 'similar', 
    1.0: 'Exacly'
})
m2m_similarity.head(3)
```

**and the result is Nan**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be:

```
m2m_similarity['analysis'] = m2m_similarity['similarity_score'].map(lambda s: 'Exacly' if round(s, 2) == 1 else ('similar' if round(s, 2) >= 0.5 else 'slightly-similar'))
```

As it would cover all the options in between.
And anyway make sure that in `similarity_score` you have numbers and not `strings`, and if they aren't actually high-precision floats that you only show the first digit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
m2m_similarity['analysis'] = m2m_similarity['similarity_score'].replace({
    0.1: 'slightly-similar', 0.2: 'slightly-similar', 0.3: 'slightly-similar', 0.4: 'slightly-similar',
    0.5: 'similar', 0.6: 'similar', 0.7: 'similar', 0.8: 'similar',0.9: 'similar', 
    1.0: 'Exacly'
})
```

Comment: using ".replace" the result is still the same

Comment: Check if the column dtype is float or not.